# How do I Authenticate to AAD using Invoke-RestMethod with ClientCredential flow using certfiicate and get the token?

Tags: azure-active-directory, invoke-restmethod

How do I Authenticate to AAD using Invoke-RestMethod with ClientCredential flow using certificate and get the token?

I tried to search for it but no success.
I can authenticate with client Secret but I want to use cert for security purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Access Token using client credential flow with using certificate.You need to generate a self singed certificate and need to upload in AzureAD application->ertificate&Secret.

You can refer this ***[Post](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-graph-api/)***, Here they have explained
in steps how you can generate the access token using the certificate.

Comment: I was looking to generate the token using cert and this solves the purpose. Earlier had issue with the cmdlets as i had saw specific limitations. I got the workaround was able to test it out yesterday and it worked. Thanks much Rahul..